# Not waiting for Javascript function respone from code behind

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

Hi I have a scenario,
    I have a list I need to save that into table before saving that I need to check that already exist or not if exist I need to show dialog to user Are you sure need to override (YES Or NO).these thing I need to do in code behind in web. before getting response(Yes or No) from user I need to wait if yes need to execute one function otherwise no execution.

I do the following in Code behind:

```
int dupCount = checkdup(id);

// Get Conformation From the User Need to Save OR Not
if (dupCount > 0){
    System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "confirm", "<script>Confirm();</script>", false);
    Thread.Sleep(8000);
    string confirmValue = hdnConform.Value;
    if (confirmValue == "Yes"){
        savemethod();
    }
    else { }
 }
 else{
     savemethod();
 }
```

In the design, I do this:

```
   function Confirm() {

    if (confirm("Do you want to save data?")) {

        document.getElementById('<%=hdnConform.ClientID %>').value = "Yes";

    } else {

    document.getElementById('<%=hdnConform.ClientID %>').value = "No";

    }       

    }
```

Now I come to the issue. While executing this, my javescript function is called very last and my code does't wait for user response (Yes or No), it is executing continually.

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking.  If I understand correctly... You want the page to check a server-side condition before posting the form?  If that's the case then you'll likely want to use AJAX to check that condition.  Look into various ways of employing AJAX in WebForms.  Basically the JavaScript code would call a server-side handler, which would perform server-side calculations and return a value, then the JavaScript would examine that value for its logic.  Also, be sure you don't *assume* that this executed correctly, you should re-validate input in the posted form.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you a refactor of your code in this way. Call server side function only if the user wants to save data.

```
function Confirm() {

    if (confirm("Do you want to save data?")) {

       $.ajax({
         url: 'your method url',
         type: "POST",
         //other parameters

        }).done(function( msg ) {
           alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
         });

    } else {

            //other code
      }       

}
```

I think that `Thread.Sleep` for this purpose is unuseful